# Bug in Action Bar tabs when changing orientation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

So I wrote this simple tab navigation. It has two tabs called "Fragment 1" and "Fragment 2". If you hit either one, it should display respective texts "Fragment 1" or "Fragment 2" in the content area. My code works fine at the start.

However, when I turn the device to change into landscape orientation, the text messes up. It displays Fragment with a combination of 1 and 2 on the same spot. I think both texts are being displayed at the same time. The text remains that way I try to change tabs after this bug occurs. This also happens when I change from landscape to portrait. What is causing this?

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tab = ab.newTab().setText(R.string.frag1).setTabListener(new MyTabListener(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
    ab.addTab(tab);

    tab = ab.newTab().setText(R.string.frag2).setTabListener(new MyTabListener(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
    ab.addTab(tab);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mFragName;

    public MyTabListener(Activity activity, String fragName) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mFragName = fragName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mFragName);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(mFragment);
        mFragment = null;

    }

}
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
    }
}
```

Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
{   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use replace() instead of add() method in your onTabSelected() method.